# Add tags to resources - power shell

Tags: azure, powershell

Im trying to assign the tags to the Resource Group while deploying it. I also use the ini file where I have my variables defined.

This is my two function that read ini file and creates the Resoure group

```
    function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath
    {
        "^\[(.+)\]" # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        "^(;.*)$" # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
        "(.+?)\s*=(.*)" # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}


function Create-ResourceGroup {
    param (
        [string] $rgName,
        [string] $saName,
        [hashtable] $tags
    )
    
    az group create --name $rgName --location "westeurope" --tags $tags


}
```

And I have the the seperate file where I call this function as below:

```
. ".\functions.ps1"

# Get variables from the INI file
$iniFilePath = "../configuration/variables.ini"
$iniContent = Get-IniContent $iniFilePath

# Get today's date
$today = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$trainerName = $iniContent["project"]["trainer"]
$projectName = $iniContent["project"]["name"]

$tags = @{
    "CreationDate" = $today
    "Trainer" = $trainerName
    "Project" = $projectName
}

# Iterate over the trainees section
foreach ($key in $iniContent["trainees"].Keys) {
    # Get the trainee name
    $traineeName = $iniContent["trainees"][$key]


    $names = $traineeName -split ' '
    $lastname = ($traineeName -split ' ')[1].Substring(0, [Math]::Min(5, $traineeName.IndexOf(" "))).ToLower()
    # RG name
    $resourceGroupName = "rg-academy-databricks-$lastname"
    # SA name
    $storageName = "stacademy$lastname"
    # DB name
    $databricksName = "dbs-academy-course-$lastname-001"


    # Call function to create resources

    Create-ResourceGroup -rgName $resourceGroupName -saName $storageName -tags $tags


}
```

the code does not fail but tags that i have defined are not passed, instead I see System.Collections.Hashtable : as its shown in the below image. I did try splatting and replaced `--tags $tags` with `--tags @tags` but did throwing the error `Missing an argument for parameter 'tags'`

[image]

Comment: Powershell is converting your hashtable $tags to a string. The toString method does not convert the values to the format you need. it just outputs the datatype.
Create a string instead of a hashtable. Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-create-optional-parameters or use the powershell module instead.

Comment: can you please elaborate, doumntation you gave is confusing. Im new to powershell

Comment: you need to transform your hashtable to a string which looks like that: key[=value] [key[=value] ...]. Because the param supports Space-separated tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct CLI syntax is `az group create ... --tags tag1=value1 tag2=value2`, so you'll want to extract the individual key-value pairs and turn each of them into a string in the form `key=value`:

```
function Create-ResourceGroup {
    param (
        [string] $rgName,
        [string] $saName,
        [hashtable] $tags
    )

    $tagArgs = @(
        $tags.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object { $_.Key,$_.Value -join '=' }
    )
    
    az group create --name $rgName --location "westeurope" --tags @tagArgs
}
```